# EJB 1.1 and disk io

Tags: java, ejb, disk

I have a question about EJB 1.1 (yes really that old ... - please dont kid me...)

So the question is one of the old ones: Why should I not do disk io within EJBs? Especially reading files.

To be more precise the use case: Its all about one file that is needed as a template for some special data export.
So it is:

- one file
- very rarely changed (for example within a special maintanance time)
- rarely read
- no heavy load

Is there any reason, why not to read that template file from disk?
Are there any technical restrictions like an ForbiddenOperationException when I try to do disk io within an EJB. I already run a test and reading and transferring is working just fine. Is that behaviour different within EJB 2.x or 3.x?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction is in the specification to allow for clustering of EJBs, which is easier if the EJB is self-contained and does not rely on the outside environment such as the file system.

Accessing the file system should work fine however, if you truly want to comply with the spec you could bundle the file inside the EJB jar and access it from the classpath using [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks Jörn, I acceppt your first argument and it nicly wraps up my understanding. But your suggestion to get the resource from the classpath does not match my use case, because I need that file to be changeable independetly from the deployment - maybe only 1 or 2 times in life time, but by the customer and not by the developer!

Comment: I just wanted to show a possible alternative, but using the filesystem should work fine in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

From [EJB Restrictions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html) :

> Enterprise beans aren't allowed to access files primarily because
>   files are not transactional resources. Allowing EJBs to access files
>   or directories in the filesystem, or to use file descriptors, would
>   compromise component distributability, and would be a security hazard.

You can pack file in a JAR so that you can read it with `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` & can change, redeploy independently.

Else, if you haven't encountered any issues with your current approach, then its fine, but isn't recommended in accordance with the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store it in database as a blob?

then you can have an admin webapp to change it from browser

and you can use ldap to authenticate/authorize the webapp

oops, sorry for making life so complicated